# Qt5 with Qt 4.7 on Ubuntu 13.04. How to install without conflicts?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5, qt4.7

I'm using Qt5 and need Qt 4.7 now. Is it possible to install it additionally on Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 0):

Having qt4 and qt5 installed on one system is always problematic and very often the source of unexplainable crashes.

Something I personally experienced: I changed audio in one of my programs from phonon to QMediaPlayer. After compilation the program crashed immediately. Even when I used the exact example in the Qt docs. Any program, which used QMediaPlayer crashed. After some research I discovered. That the qt5 multimedia class linked against a gstreamer lib, which linked against libproxy, which had a module, which linked against Qt4.

So: My program -> Qt5 -> libgstreamer -> libproxy -> Qt4 = Crash.

I asked on the Qt mailing ist. It is a known problem. No workaround available. Can always happen when two Qt versions with different major numbers are installed on the same system.

So back to your question: Even if Ubuntu allows it, it is not a good idea to do it.